# Change the color of the rect in UIVIew in ios?

Tags: ios

I have an UIView `X` which is green color of size (0,0,100,100). I need to change the green color to clear color of that view in particular portion like rect(30,30, 40, 40). So only I can see the view that behind `X`.

Thanks in advance

Comment: add your code here what you did

Comment: Can u please note down the mistakes in my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Try this, I hope this would will help..


 - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect { 

    CGRect greenRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, rect.size.width, rect.size.height/2.0);
    // Fill the rectangle with grey
    [[UIColor greenColor] setFill];
    UIRectFill( topRect );

    CGRect clearRect = CGRectMake(0, rect.size.height/2.0, rect.size.width, rect.size.height/2.0);
    [[UIColor clearColor] setFill];
    UIRectFill( bottomRect );

}
```

Comment: Hi, I need clarification...I ll pass a view(green color) and rect to a function that function should changed that rect position of the view to clear color. In the above code I can't get what is topRect and bottomRect...Is it possible to do it with out subclassing the UIView?